# fullPage.js — No custom easingcss3 when autoScrolling set to false

Tags: css, fullpage.js, easing

in fullPage.js when setting options for normal scrolling, for example:

```
autoScrolling: false,
easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)'
```

and scroll by an anchor link the defined css easing will not work.
Instead it is a linear/ease transition.

Is this a bug or simply not possible? Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/7s34u1u1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and scroll by an anchor link the defined css easing will not work. Instead it is a linear/ease transition.

When using `autoScrolling:false` fullpage.js is not using css3 to scroll but the jQuery scrollTop property. As it is just scrolling a normal site with a scroll bar.

Use the `easing` option instead.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, that is plausible. Did not think about that. I will check out jQuery easing instead.